# How to prevent edit in copy of arraylist in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which is assigned to two ArrayList variables. So it assigned the memory location of the primary to the other two. But I need a variable that should not change the parent and another one.

```kotlin
data class Item(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String
)


val master: Arraylist<Item> = items // from network
val copy1 = master
val copy2 = master

copy2[0].name = "new name here"
```

From the above code, we are changing the name of all. But my requirement is to make a copy of the master and change it only in copy2

Comment: Are you sure your example code is correct? The variable `copy2` has the same type as `master` which is an `ArrayList<Item>`, not an `Item`. So I do not think that it is possible to call `copy2.name`.

Comment: @vincrichaud I already went through these answers. I will agin check and update. Also, if I assign an item from the list to a variable `val item = master.get(0)`. If i changes the item property, it will also affect all three. I need this scenario (single item assignment) too.

Comment: @KarstenGabriel Extremely sorry. Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of your `master` list by copying all contained items:

```
fun List<Item>.copy() = map{ it.copy() }
```

Then, when you write

```
val copy2 = master.copy()
```

You have a copy of `master` consisting of (shallow) copies of the contained elements in `master`.

(see [Kotlin documentation on copying data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying))

Now changing elements in `copy2` does not change the corresponding elements in `master` or `copy1`.